# MYSql Load Contents Of URL INTO Table

Tags: mysql

I was wondering if there is a way of inserting into a table the return value from a url

Something like

LOAD DATA 'http://www.google.com' INTO TABLE test_table

Comment: not without a application layer in between ( curl->application->db )

Comment: I have used curl before, how's it done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, It may help you to get the data from the http://google.com website

```
 http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D'http://google.com'&format=xml&callback=callback
```